VS Code C++ remote development - Add remote library
I am new to c++ app.
I have visual studio installed on my Windows system. I have installed c c++ and remote connection plugin in visual studio. C++ compiler gcc is installed on another linux machine. All libraries required for project compilation is installed on linux machine.
I am writing an c++ program which need library which is on linux machine.
How do i add those remote library in my application in visual studio.
Thanks
========Code===========
I have added path in tasks.json-
"tasks": \[
{
"type": "cppbuild",
"label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
"command": "/usr/bin/g++",
"args": \[
"-fdiagnostics-color=always",
"-g",
"${file}",
"-o",
"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
"-I/usr/bin/",
"-L/usr/bin/"
\],

I have also added path in c_app_properties.json -
configurations": \[
{
"name": "Linux",
"defines": \[\],
"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
"cStandard": "c11",
"cppStandard": "c++17",
"intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
"includePath": \[
"test/rapidjson/\*",
"/usr/bin/"
\]


What problem are you encountering?

Your tasks.json specifies the library folder but doesn't actually link to any library other than what your compiler adds for the standard library.

Also remember that c_cpp_properties.json is not involved in compiling.

You don't have "Visual Studio" installed, you have "Visual Studio Code" installed and that is a BIG difference. Is there a reason you're not using "Visual Studio Community Edition" (it is a lot easier to use for beginners)

Yes, I am using visual studio code. I am getting an error while running program in vs code.

I am getting an error while running program in vs code. It's essential to always copy and paste the exact text of the error message and add it to your question as text. Also add the exact text of the build command again as text and not a picture. Your failure to show the details only adds delay to anyone who wants to help because we are not sitting at your PC and can't see you screen / debug it ourselves.
